# How to add a 3rd party Jquery Library in React Functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use a 3rd library only for my homepage in a React application. The problem is : the library is developed with Jquery : [www.npmjs.com/package/fullview](http://www.npmjs.com/package/fullview)

I need to import : Jquery, js file and css file.

so far, I haven't found any way to import this type of library into a functional component. Only class components.

Can I import these files directly in index.html with `<script>` or i need to import them in my component with import ... from "..."

Thank you !

Comment: Why not make a class component that does what you need, then use that component within your function component?

Answer (score -2):

You can add jquery CDN in your public/index.html like this:

```
//public/index.html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
       <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
       <meta
         name="description"
         content="Web site created using create-react-app"
       />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
 <title>React App</title>
</head>
 <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
     ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

no need to import jquery in component or something else now jquery is avalible golobally.

Comment: OK, so now that jQuery is loaded into the page (1) How do you load the plugin and (2) How do you get the plugin to interact with the DOM generated by React? Your answer hasn't addressed the actual problem.

Comment: That's an old version of jQuery that's been superseded. There's no reason to use something that out of date.

Comment: There's a lot of boilerplate in this answer which (1) doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem and (2) depends on some tool (that you haven't mentioned) to preprocess the HTML and fill in placeholders with actual URLs.

Comment: Yes thank you Quentin, but it's nice of him to help me

Comment: @Tristan — This isn't what I'd call helpful, it's a waste of time, which isn't nice.

Comment: @quentin I am sure that while routing jquery will be available because react doesn't change the index .html the only thing that changes is occurs inside <div id="root"></div> as meta data not changing while routing.

Comment: @PaimanRasoli — At no point did I suggest that this would cause a problem with routing.

Comment: @quentin please see your first comment question number 2.

Comment: @PaimanRasoli — I don't see how you interpreted me pointing out that you failed to explain how to integrate the plugin the question is asking about with React as a complaint that jQuery would break with routing.